# Select box initialized after not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the value of a select box but it always bring me the first value.

At the begin the select is empty. I press a button that shows the modal and loads the info of the select box. I think the problem comes 'cause I'm not loading the select options until the button is pressed because I tried with another select and it worked well

this is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalPremios" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Premios</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="premios" class="modal-body">
                <jsp:include page="../frag/premios-list-frag.jsp"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the form inside the modal:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="quiniela.id" value="${quiniela.id }"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="plantillaOwnerQuiniela" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Quiniela</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select class="form-control" name="quiniela.plantillaOwnerQuiniela" id="plantillaOwnerQuiniela"  ${read }>
                <c:forEach items="${lista2 }" var="pl">
                    <option value="${pl.id }"
                    <c:if test="${pl.id == quiniela.plantillaOwnerQuiniela.id}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${pl.nombrePlantillaOwner} - ${pl.precioQuiniela}Bs</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is how i show the modal:

```
$("#myModal").modal("show");
```

I've read that maybe the element is not present in the Dom, then I've tried using this function to see if something happen but It doesn't work.

```
$('#plantillaOwnerQuiniela').on('change',function() {
    var selectVal = $('#plantillaOwnerQuiniela :selected').val();
    alert(selectVal);
});
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3 modal.. I really couldn't figure out how to try your answer with my code, I show my modal diferently

Comment: it wont work 'cause I'm using struts2 also.. and I'm filling the select box data calling an action when I show the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem by including the modal-body class when trying to read the value of if. Like this:

```
$('.modal-body #plantillaOwnerQuiniela :selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it seems like the `plantillaOwnerQuiniela` element is not present in the DOM at the time you are binding your `change` listener.

Try the following:

```
$("body").on("change", "#plantillaOwnerQuiniela", function(e){
    var selectVal = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    alert(selectVal);
});
```

Use `.on()` to attach the listener to `body` and delegate it to the select, vs. attaching to the select itself; which may or may not be present on pageload.

Comment: I think you're right because the select start being empty and then I press the button create and it loads the info into the form and then show the modal. But this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the change event to the popover initialize method like this:

```
$('.button').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
        return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }                 
}).parent().delegate('#plantillaOwnerQuiniela', 'change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/nUVEm/) is the example !